# Factory to construct a FineTime out of many kinds of objects

Tags: java, factory-method, cyclomatic-complexity

Any suggestions to help refactor this method? I thought maybe some kind of factory to allocate the right type?

```
public static FineTime getFineTime(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //FineTime
    if (o instanceof FineTime) {
        return (FineTime ) o;
    }
    //Long
    if (o instanceof Long) {
        return new FineTime((Long ) o);
    }
    //Int
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        return new FineTime((Integer ) o);
    }
    //Date
    if (o instanceof Date) {
        try {
            return DateConverter.dateToFineTime((Date ) o);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(Date) failed", iae);
        }
    }
    //String
    if (o instanceof String) {
        String date = (String ) o;
        //TAI
        try {
            return _stfFormatTai.parse(date);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "_stfFormatTai.parse(String) failed", iae);
        }
        //UTC
        try {
            return _stfFormatUtc.parse(date);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "_stfFormatUtc.parse(String) failed", iae);
        }
        //dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
        try {
            return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(date));
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(String) failed", pe);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(String) failed", iae);
        }
        //dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
        try {
            return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(date));
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            //Try another coverter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(String) failed", pe);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Try another converter
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(String) failed", iae);
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info("Could not convert " + StringUtil.asString(o) + " to FineTime");
    //No converter found, return 'null'
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be related to the [Herschel Interactive Processing Environment](http://herschel.esac.esa.int/hcss-doc-13.0/).

Comment: What's the root cause of this mess? Where does `Object o` come from, and why is its type unknown?

Answer (score 4):

Overloading!

```
public static FineTime getFineTime(Long o){
    if(o == null){ return null; }
    return new FineTime(o);
}

public static FineTime getFineTime(Integer o){
    if(o == null){ return null; }
    return new FineTime(o);
}

public static FineTime getFineTime(FineTime o){
    return o;
}

public static FineTime getFineTime(Date o){
    if(o == null){ return null; }
    try {
        return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(o);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(Date) failed", iae);
        return null;
    }
}

public static FineTime getFineTime(String date){
    if(date == null){ return null; }
    //TAI
    try {
        return _stfFormatTai.parse(date);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "_stfFormatTai.parse(String) failed", iae);
    }
    //UTC
    try {
        return _stfFormatUtc.parse(date);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "_stfFormatUtc.parse(String) failed", iae);
    }
    //dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
    try {
        return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(String) failed", pe);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat1.parse(String) failed", iae);
    }
    //dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
    try {
        return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        //Try another coverter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(String) failed", pe);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(_sdfFormat2.parse(String) failed", iae);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And a default implementation

```
public static FineTime getFineTime(Object o){
    LOGGER.info("Could not convert " + StringUtil.asString(o) + " to FineTime");
    //No converter found, return 'null'
    return null;
}
```

And gone are most of your troubles.

The problem in this case, however, is that you do need to know what type your object has. You cannot "just" insert an object and get a value out. To do so anyway seems to imply bad design.

If you wanted to go that direction anyway, consider making a map of Class, Converter of sorts.

Something else you could do is leave the method you have right now as is, and just wrap your `String` and `Date` conversions in a separate function. That would significantly simplify the method as well, boiling down to "if integer, finetime via integer, if long, finetime via long, if string, finetime via string, if date, finetime via date, else log error and return null".

Comment: Using exceptions for a flow control is an anti-pattern. Exceptions are for... exceptional situations.

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski not my code. Write thine own review =)

Answer (score 4):

Eh, the overloading part doesn't help you much, except adding more
methods with more code.

More importantly, trying the different date options looks, at the
moment, quite horrible.  Most of the comments, with the exception of the
date format description (which should be obvious from the format
variable as well), are redundant as well.  I'd also prefer early
returns, at least that way you don't have to read further to see whether
something else be executed.

Now, it would be better if `_stfFormatTai` and `_stfFormatUtc` would
also return something that's passed on to
`DateConverter.dateToFineTime`, but if that's not viable, there're
basically two blocks, one with the conversion, one without.

And finally the `catch` blocks should (unless you're not on Java 7 yet
ಠ_ಠ) catch two exception types at once.

Without types it's hard to say, but, if all the format objects are of
the same type, you could put them in a list and try them one after
another in a loop like:

```
for (Format format : formats) {
    try {
        return format.parse(date);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | ParseException e) {
        // log a warning
    }
}
```

Comment: If my hunch is right `_stfFormatTai`/`_stfFormatUtc` are [`SimpleTimeFormat`](http://herschel.esac.esa.int/hcss-doc-13.0/load/hcss_drm/api/herschel/share/fltdyn/time/SimpleTimeFormat.html) objects, and `_sdfFormat1`/`_sdfFormat2` are the regular `SimpleDateFormatter` objects. Still a good suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use the overloading idea in [@Pimgd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120867/24141)'s answer and take things one step further when you later use `SimpleDateFormatter` (`_sdfFormat1`/`_sdfFormat2`?) to parse `String`s:

```
// from @Pimgd's answer
public static FineTime getFineTime(Date o){
    if(o == null){ return null; }
    try {
        return DateConverter.dateToFineTime(o);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //Try another converter
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "DateConverter.dateToFineTime(Date) failed", iae);
        return null;
    }
}

// suggestion
public static FineTime getFineTime(String o) {
    // using @ferada's suggestion here to loop through your parsers
    for (TimeFormat parser : simpleTimeFormatParsers) {
        // attempt to parse the String
    }
    for (DateFormat parser : simpleDateFormatParsers) {
        try {
            return getFineTime(parser.parse(o));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```